# How to create a custom windows 7 USB image?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, iso-image, sysprep

I'm working as IT support engineer ,I'm really tired of installing Win 7 on different laptops from different brand ,I have to find the drivers for each model ...**what I want to do is create a custom image for each laptop model with pre installed Ms Office and drivers ...when any laptop from a certain model come to my office ...I will just create a USB image for the laptop and install it  .**

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options. If you have access to a Windows Server - you can use the Microsoft Deployment Toolkit which is extremely powerful but has a learning curve.

There are also some other tools that will create custom install images like NTlite, which is ok but not as powerful as MDT.

https://www.ntlite.com/download/

Good luck!